# Convert d.getDay() to mon, tue

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting d.getDay but its giving me like 0 for Sunday, Is there any direct way to get Sunday instead of 0. I have searched but couldn't find any. I dont want to do like comparing 0 then creating string with "Sun" and so on.....

Thanks

Comment: Like, totally... http://stackoverflow.com/users/739323/programmer?tab=reputation See all those negatives? That's because you do a poor job creating questions. You should think about that some.

Comment: What culture do you want the String representation in? And what's `d` in the first place? (I hope it's not a `java.util.Date`... there's a reason all those methods in `Date` are deprecated.)

Comment: Create a method in one place to handle this.  If you don't like doing a task, create a tool to automate it for you so you never have to do it again.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you remind me and the author(or point me to a reference) why Date is deprecated?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: `Date` isn't, but all the methods like `getDay` are. `Date` represents a single instant in time, without any reference to a particular time zone or calendar system. The day of the week I'm currently experiencing may not be the same as the one you're experiencing.

Comment: Use JODA, _please._  Don't use `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet If he is using the date on a server, then it wouldn't matter when (or where) the client called the method from, all the day/time records will be relevent to each other because it will all be based on the time/day of the server.

Comment: @Louis I'm not formiliar to JODA, can you provide some documentation on it please?

Comment: @MattWestlake: Who said there's even a server involved? We simply have no context here. Even if there *is* a server involved, who's to say that the server time zone is the appropriate one to use? (Did you do a search for Joda by the way? For me, the first link is obviously a useful one.)

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ has all the docs, and some of the reasons why you _shouldn't_ use the built-in Java libs.

Comment: @AHungerArtist will keep in mind...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
//US locale is used 
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
//dateFormat.setTimeZone(); optionally specify timezone
String day = dateFormat.format(dateInstance);
```

Comment: Without knowing which time zone or locale we're meant to be talking about, this sounds like a bad idea to me. These are important things to take into account.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
String dayString = sdf.format(date));
```

Use the custom `SimpleFormat` constructor if you want to get the day name in other languages (see documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)): 
Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE",Locale.FRENCH);
String dayString = sdf.format(date));
```

Will return the day's name in french.